# Connection Pool configuration / error in SonarQube

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, sonarqube

from time to time I have the following error in my logs:

> Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a  connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
>
> The error may exist in org.sonar.core.issue.db.ActionPlanMapper
>
> The error may involve org.sonar.core.issue.db.ActionPlanMapper.findByKeys
>
> The error occurred while executing a query

How should I adjust my connection pool settings so that this doesn't occur anymore?

```
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=25
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=15000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
```

Comment: Most likely you are not closing connections in your code, so they are not returned to the pool; or you need more connections than your pool provides met the current `maxActive` setting. It is impossible to tell from the information you provided.

Comment: This issue is occuring in SonarQube, so I don't know how they are handling their connections.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest increasing the number of `maxActive` and see if it helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to `http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-188`, you can try to update your connection settings in file: **`conf/sonar.properties`**
with adding "autoreconnect".

**Example:**

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8?autoReconnect=true
```